# Best way to run rails background jobs with Openshift

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, openshift, resque, sidekiq

I have a rails 3.2.13 application on OPENSHIFT. I need the best way to manage background jobs, for example daily, weekly or monthly search alerts (when users can subscribe to the search they made and get email alerts with new products). 
I have installed REDIS cartridge according to [these instructions](https://blog.openshift.com/enabling-redis-for-your-app/).
There are OPENSHIFT cartridges available for [Resque](https://github.com/pbrazdil/openshift-resque-cartridge) and [Sidekiq](https://github.com/openshift-cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-sidekiq), but installation commands do not work.

I managed to install Resque as a gem according to these [instructions](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/topics/performance/background_jobs.html) and it is working when I start it with the rake command: 
`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUE='*'`
But the worker is stopped as soon as I close command line tool. When I use action-hooks for the same rake task, it works only for some period of time and then I have to restart the worker again. How can I start a worker only once on production?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be best off creating rake tasks for what you need done and then using cron to fire them off when you need them to run.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I thought about it too. But then how can I start a cron job from my rails controller (if the job is not scheduled). For example, every time a new product is created, I have to search for users subscribed to this type of product and send them email with updates.

Comment: Setup your rake task to look for new products that were created, then it can email everyone who is subscribed, have it run every hour or something would probably be often enough.

Comment: If the rake task will run every hour or often, will it influence site performance? I heard running rake task will load entire Rails stack and can eat up a lot of CPU and memory.

Comment: It's possible, it will definitely use some cpu and memory

Comment: I have found out that there is foreman cartridge for openshift. I installed it as described [here](https://github.com/ncdc/openshift-foreman-cartridge) and my resque worker started working. Isn't it a better way to handle background job like search alerts than cron and rake? Or you still suggest me to use cron with sheduled rake task?